# How to access header values of request in Java Restlet?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, request, restlet

I am developing web services using **Restlet Java**.

For this I want to protect some webservices from unauthorized clients. So I have written Filter class. In that Filter class I want to get the **headers**  of the Request. But I am getting the following error -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.restlet.engine.http.HttpRequest cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

The coding is -

```
public class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {

        int result = STOP;

        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String user_token = httpReq.getHeader("auth");

        if(user_token.equals("xyz")) {
            result = CONTINUE;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Please suggest me a way to access the header values of Request in Java Restlet?**

Comment: What version number of Restlet are you using?

Comment: I'm using Restlet v2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem using

```
Form headers = (Form) request.getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
String user_token = headers.getFirstValue("Location");
```

I found this http://blog.yudongli.com/2009/12/get-request-header-in-restlet_13.html link useful.

Comment: You can just do `request.getHeaders()`. Tested in Restlet 2.3.4

Answer (score 2):

Please also notice that Restlet provides an API for RESTful application. This means that you can access standard headers using this API. In most cases, you donn't need to use the attribute named "org.restlet.http.headers".

For example, if you want to set a Location header in the response, you add this code:

```
getResponse().setLocationRef("http://...");
```

Otherwise, since you talk about security, Restlet provides a generic API to support such aspect (see classes ChallengeAuthenticator, Verifier, Enroler).

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Restlet 2.1-RC3 this is the way to get it

```
 Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
 String auth = headers.getFirstValue("auth");
```

This is exactly how it's worked for me. None of the answers above did it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How would you handle seeking to parse an ID in the GET header from a client request ?
Would you approach this in the same manner ?

Since the:

```
Form headers = (Form) getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
```

returns all the header information and

```
String hID = headers.getFirstValue("Location");
```

gets the location(s)

How would you handle parsing out the ID ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Series headers = (Series) getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
String origin = headers.getFirstValue("Origin");`
```

This is just an example of getting the Origin header. If you want to get Location, just change to headers.getFirstValue("Location");

As in the new version of Restlet, getRequestAttributes().get() returns Series instead of Form.

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: This is just an example of getting the Origin header. If you want to get Location, just change to headers.getFirstValue("Location");

Comment: As in the new version of Restlet, getRequestAttributes().get() returns Series instead of Form.

Comment: This should be part of your answer and not a comment.