# Read out custom Header from a Restlet Request

Tags: java, rest, httprequest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I need to read out a custom header from a Restlet Request.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743785/how-to-access-header-values-of-request-in-java-restlet) I tried

```
Form headers = (Form) request.getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
String ltpaToken = headers.getFirstValue("LtpaToken2");
```

But this results in the following exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.restlet.util.Series cannot be cast to org.restlet.data.Form

Therefore, how can I read out this custom header?

Thanks and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was how to achive this in restlet 2.0.x I'm assuming that you are using a more recent version?  at 2.1.x try

```
    Series<Header> series = (Series<Header>)getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
    series.getFirst("LtpaToken2");
```

there was mention of a short cut method, so that you did not need the magic String `org.restlet.http.headers` but I'm not sure which version that was / is being introduced in.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderConstants#ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS class variable instead of "org.restlet.http.headers".

If you're not afraid of class casting:

```
((HttpRequest) getRequest()).getHeaders();
```