# Restlet clientResource post returns http error 415

Tags: java, json, restlet

I'm trying to post a `JSON` to some `REST` service, but I always end up with a `HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type`.

The **REST Documentation** clearly notes I should use `application/json`, which I do. Surely I must be overlooking something.

```
public JSONObject fetchResponse() throws ResourceException, JSONException, IOException {
    JRRequest jr = new JRRequest();

    jr.setJql(jql);
    jr.setMaxResults(Integer.parseInt(maxresults));
    jr.setFields(fields);

    Gson json = new Gson();
    String payload = json.toJson(jr);


    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(getClientResource(restUri).post(payload,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).getText());

    return jsObj;
}


private ClientResource getClientResource(String uri) {
    ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(uri);
    Application app = new Application();
    clientResource.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,username, password);
    return clientResource;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `Restlet` server? or are you posting on a different server like `Node` or `PHP`?

Comment: Posting on a different server, JIRA actually (Tomcat).

Comment: I've tried the Advanced REST client in Chrome, posting a json payload with application/json, and it works fine. So the server's definitely working fine.

Comment: Have you checked if the `JSON` is malformed or did some logs on the request headers? Printing the headers is shown in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743785/how-to-access-header-values-of-request-in-java-restlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. Instead of doing it all in one line, I tried this:

```
    Representation rep = new StringRepresentation(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(getClientResource(restUri).post(rep).getText());
```

And it works now!

Comment: If this solved your problem, I think you should accept this as the answer